# Pages: How can I make a new character style permanent?

Tags: pages, formatting

(Pages 8.1 on 2017 Macbook).

I made a couple of new character styles when editing a document.  They show up in the inspector correctly, but only when editing that particular document.

I'd like to make them available for all documents, but haven't worked out how to do it.

Comment: You may need to save it as a template.